# Unit testing verify object returned from a callback in anonymous class

Tags: java, unit-testing, callback, mocking, anonymous-class

I'm new to unit testing and I'm not sure how to approuch this case, so I would appreciate your input.

Relevant code:

```
public class Repository {

@Override
public void getUnifiedFoo(@NonNull final Foo foo1,
        @NonNull final GetUnifiedFooCallback getUnifiedFooCallback) {

    fooDataSource.getFoo2(foo1,new GetFoo2Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onGetFooSuccess(Foo foo2) {
                    UnifiedFoo unifiedFoo= createUnifiedFoo(foo1, foo2);
                    getUnifiedFooCallback.onGetSuccess(unifiedFoo);
                }

                @Override
                public void onGetMedicationCallbackFailure(Throwable t) {
                    getUnifiedFooCallback.onGetFailure(t);
                }
            });
      }
}

private createUnifiedFoo(Foo foo1, Foo foo2){

   return new UnifiedFoo(
              foo1.getMember1,
              foo1.getMember2,
              foo2.getMember3,
              foo2.getMember4,
      );
}
```

My questions are:

1. Shoud 'createUnifiedFoo(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)' be package private and be tested separately?
2. In that context, if yes it sould, is there any point in testing that 1 methods (in this case fooDataSource.getFoo(...)) is called?
3. If it's acceptible to test 'createUnifiedFoo...' when getting called back in the anonymous class, how do I capture the callback so that when 'onGetFooSuccess(Foo foo2)' is called, I take foo1 stub, foo2 stub and assert equeal their fields to verfiy that they contain the correct values?

Thank you.

Comment: When is `createUnifiedFoo` ever going to return `null`? Not going to happen.

Comment: You are correct... I adjusted to code...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of opinion actually.

Personally, I would move the `createUnifiedFoo` to a different class

```
class FooUnifier {
    public UnifiedFoo of(Foo1 f1, Foo2 f2) {...
}
```

so in the repository you'd have

```
class Repository {
    FooUnifier unifier = new FooUnifier(); // or @Autowired

        ...
        getUnifiedFooCallback.onGetSuccess(unifier.of(foo1, foo2));
}
```

and in the unit test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class Test {
    @InjectMocks
    Repository sut;

    @Mock
    FooDatasource datasource;
    @Mock
    FooUnifier unifier;
    @Mock
    UnifiedFoo unifiedFoo;
    @Mock
    GetUnifiedFooCallback callback;

    @Before
    public void mockUnifiedFoo()
        when(unifier.of(any(), any())).thenReturn(unifiedFoo);
    }
}
```

This will create mocks and set them to the `Repository`'s member, allowing you to create test cases like this

```
@Test
public void unificationSuccess() {
    Foo1 foo1 = mock(Foo1.class);
    Foo2 foo2 = mock(Foo2.class);
    when(datasource.getFoo2(foo1, eq(callback)))
       .then(i -> {
           callback.onGetSuccess(unifiedFoo);
       });
    sut.getUnifiedFoo(foo1, callback);

    // make sure the unified foo was created
    verify(unifier).of(foo1, foo2);
    // make sure the callback was called
    verify(callback).onGetSuccess(unifiedFoo);
}
```

so basically you setup your test case and then verify that all the correct calls are made with the right arguments.

You can test the correct behavior of the `FooUnifier` separately.

Comment: To my knowledge, move the unified method to a separate class isn't the way to go because of separation of concerns.
In my case, only the Repository is responsible for creating UnifiedFoo.
The construction of the object has to be in a place that only Repository can access.

Comment: @henengel Conventionally, a "repository"'s responsibility is database access, and the factory pattern implemented here is kind of breaking Single Responsibility. But as I said, it is a matter of opinion to a degree. It is simpler to test the way I designed it; you won't be able to mock your factory method - but that's fine, you can assert the created `UnifiedFoo`'s values as well.